# Printing and returning the correct list

Tags: java, list

I'm currently working on the below question

```
// It should return the greatest common factor
    // between two numbers.  
    //
    // Examples of greatestCommonFactor:
    //   greatestCommonFactor(6, 4)   // returns 2
    //   greatestCommonFactor(7, 9)   // returns 1
    //   greatestCommonFactor(20, 30) // returns 10
    //
    // Hint: start a counter from 1 and try to divide both
    // numbers by the counter. If the remainder of both divisions
    // is 0, then the counter is a common factor. Continue incrementing
    // the counter to find the greatest common factor. Use a while loop
    // to increment the counter.
```

My code is shown below

```
public static List greatestCommonFactor(int a, int b){
        int i = 1 ;
        List topnum = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList <Integer> factor = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (i <= a || i <= b ){
            i++;
        }
        if (a%i == 0 && b%i == 0){
            factor.add(i);  
        }
        else if (a%i <= 1 || b%i <= 1){
            Collections.sort(factor);
            List<Integer> topnum1 = factor.subList(factor.size() - 1, factor.size());

        }
        return topnum;
    }
```

I'm having an issue getting the right output. Currently I'm getting `[]` as output, which is strange. I can't seem to get `topnum` into the `List<Integer>` line without getting an error either, so this is about what I can manage.

Anyone has any tips to get me to print the elements from `topnum1` to solve this tutorial?

Comment: you never do something with `topnum` after you create it! of course it's returned empty.

Comment: When understanding your task and the comment right, the function greatestCommonFactor() should return an int instead of a List, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop does nothing. You should probably put your condition inside it, or it would only be tested for the last value of i.

```
while (i <= a || i <= b ){
    if (a%i == 0 && b%i == 0){
        factor.add(i);  
    }
    i++;
}
```

Beside that, you add elements to `factor` list (at least you would after the fix), and put the last element of that list in `topnum1`, but your method returns `topnum` which remains empty.

Finally, your `else if (a%i <= 1 || b%i <= 1)` is unclear to me. And you don't need to sort the `factor` list. It will already be sorted. Actually, you don't need that list at all, just keep the largest `i` that is a common factor and return it.

This will make the code much more simple :

```
public static int greatestCommonFactor(int a, int b)
{
    int result = 1;
    int i = 1 ;
    while (i <= a && i <= b){
        if (a%i == 0 && b%i == 0){
            result = i;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: you've forgotten the i++

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually change the value of `topnum` anywhere...

All you did is create it at the top with `List topnum = new ArrayList();`, then returned it at the bottom with `return topnum;`. You didn't add anything to it.

If you don't know how to add something to a list, you use `.add()`:

```
 topnum.add(7);
```

That will at `7` to `topnum`.